# NuGet Package with SpecFlow Hooks

Tags: c#, bdd, specflow, extentreports

I have created a SpecFlow hooks class to generate Extent Report in BDD Specflow C# project. It is working fine and the report got generated.

```
[BeforeTestRun]
public static void InitializeReport()
        {
            //Initialize Extent report before test starts
            var htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter(reportPath);
            htmlReporter.Config.Theme = Theme.Dark;

            //Attach report to reporter
            extent = new AventStack.ExtentReports.ExtentReports();
            extent.AttachReporter(htmlReporter);
        }

[AfterTestRun]
public static AfterTests()
        {
            //Flush report once test completes
            extent.Flush();
        }
```

To reuse the same, I have made this as a NuGet library and imported in another project. But the report is not getting generated. Do we need to create object for hooks class to invoke it?
Could anyone please suggest how to trigger SpecFlow hooks in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have added `[Binding]` attribute above your class declaration and you don't have multiple [BeforeTestRun] or [AfterTestRun] attributes.

Using multiple `[BeforeTestRun]` or `[AfterTestRun]` should work fine but not sure in your case.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem yesterday. You need to update Specflow to the newest version Specflow 3.0.x still had the bug where the `[AfterTestRun]` hook wasn't executed(for years).